# Count all dates within a 6 month period rather than overall

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to output what every salesperson has sold in the last six months but what I am using counts all dates and outputs them.

```
SELECT SalespersonNo, COUNT (SalespersonNo) AS ['CarsSold']
FROM CarForSale
WHERE DateSold > '01/08/2018'
GROUP BY SalespersonNo;
```

As I said above, it outputs all the dates added up instead of what I want which is for it to add up all the cars sold in the past 6 months

These are the results I am getting:

```
SalespersonNo   'CarsSold'
100001           4
100002           1
100003           1
100004           4
100005           2
100010           1
100011           2
100012           2
100015           1
100017           2
100020           2
```

I am aiming to get results like this:

```
SalespersonNo   'CarsSold'
100001           3
100003           1
100004           3
100005           1
100011           2
100015           1
100017           2
100020           1
```

Comment: Please show some sample data, the results you are getting and the results you are expecting.

Comment: `'01/08/2018'`  is a lot longer ago that 2 months, is that not the problem here..? Also your title say "6" but your question "two"; what are you *really* after?

Comment: I've edited my text sorry about that, I've now added what results I get plus what I want, thanks!

Comment: We need to see some starting data as well, and it needs to include the date since thats critical to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SalespersonNo,
   COUNT(SalespersonNo) AS [CarsSoldTotal],
   COUNT(CASE WHEN DateSold > DATEADD(mm, -6, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS [CarsSold6Month]
FROM CarForSale
WHERE DateSold > '01/08/2018'
GROUP BY SalespersonNo;
```

Comment: Hi, this is bringing up a syntax error on the third land, it highlights "WHEN"